# Не отображается картинка поста

Tags: php, html, laravel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]**
У меня есть вот такой код, нужно вставить картинку для поста из базы. В базе у меня есть
id
created_at
updated_at
image_name
image_path   поля.

```
@extends('leyout')
@section('title')
BlogVlog
@endsection
@section('main_content')
<div class="container">
<div class=".container text-primary">
  @foreach ( $posts as $post )
<div class="card" style="width:22rem;display: inline-block; border: 10px solid ;border-radius: 30px;margin-top:10px">
  <img src="{{ asset('storage/' ).$image_path }}" class="card-img-top" alt="image">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{ $post->title }}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">{{ $post->desc }}</p>
    <p class="card-text">{{ $post->created_at }}</p>
 </div>
</div>
@endforeach
</div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**

Comment: Что хранится в `$image_path`?

Comment: [Variable inside of asset declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755369/variable-inside-of-asset-declaration). И такой вопрос, откуда вообще берется этот `$image_path`? Может должно быть что-то вроде `$post->image_path`?

Comment: так тоже пробовал не работает

Comment: `{{ asset($post->image_path) }}` и лучше чтобы изображения не имели киррилических символов и пробелов в названии, из-за этого можете столкнуться с рядом проблем в дальнейшем.

Comment: не помогло к сожелению, но путь правильно показывает  в инспекте

Comment: А по прямой ссылке это ихображение доступно?

Comment: да  если по прямой ссылке то да

Comment: А нет никаких ошибок по типу `invalid property value` из-за того что у Вас пробелы в названиях файлов? И в пути к файлу, когда Вы смотрите через инспектор, пробел заменяется на `%20`?

Comment: нету картинка в базу добавляется, но  в странице не показывает

Comment: В консоли нет 404 ошибок, в src путь правильный, по прямой ссылке доступен, но изображения нет? Может, дело в стилях, и картинка скрывается?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать другой браузер, или приватную вкладку. Хром очень любит кешировать 404е ответы